# Use flexmark-java to clean markdown

Tags: java, markdown

Within a Java application, I would need to convert marked-down text into simple plain text instead of html (for example dropping all links addresses, bold and italic markers).

Which is the best way to do this? I was thinking using a markdown library like [fleaxmark](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java). But I cant find this feature at first sight. Is it there? Are there other better alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

[Commonmark](https://github.com/atlassian/commonmark-java) supports rendering to text, by using `org.commonmark.renderer.text.TextContentRenderer` instead of the default HTML renderer. Not sure what it does with newlines, but worth a try.

**Original answer, using flexmark HTML + JSoup**

---

The ideal solution would be to implement a custom Renderer for flexmark, but this would force you to write a model-to-string for all language features in markdown. Unless it supports this out of the box, but I'm not aware of this feature...

A simpler solution may be to use flexmark (or any other lightweight markdown renderer) and let it create the HTML. After that, just run the generated HTML through https://jsoup.org/ and let it extract the text:

```
Jsoup.parse(htmlInputStream).text();
```

> String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.text()
>   Gets the combined text of this element and all its children. Whitespace is normalized and trimmed.
>
> For example, given HTML `<p>Hello <b>there</b> now! </p>`, p.text() returns `Hello there now!`

We use this approach to get a "preview" of the text entered in a rich content editor (summernote), after being sanitized with `org.owasp.html.HtmlSanitizer`.

Answer (score 0):

flexmark also have mark down to text feature.
[checkout this](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java/blob/master/flexmark-java-samples/src/com/vladsch/flexmark/java/samples/MarkdownToText.java)